# Loading data from glue to snowflake

Tags: mongodb, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-glue

I am trying to run an ETL job on glue where I am extracting data into a spark dataframe from a mongodb into glue and load it into snowflake.

This is the sample schema of the Spark dataframe

```
|-- login: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- login_attempts: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- last_attempt: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- notifications: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bot_review_queue: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bot_review_queue_web_push: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bot_review_queue_web_push_admin: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- weekly_account_summary: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- enabled: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- weekly_summary: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- enabled: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- day: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- hour: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- minute: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- query: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- email_address: string (nullable = true)
```

I am trying to load the data into snowflake as it is and struct columns as json payload in snowflake but it throws the following error

```
An error occurred while calling o81.collectToPython.com.mongodb.spark.exceptions.MongoTypeConversionException:Cannot cast ARRAY into a StructType
```

I also tried to cast the struct columns into string and load it but it throws more or less the same error

```
An error occurred while calling o106.save.  com.mongodb.spark.exceptions.MongoTypeConversionException: Cannot cast STRING into a StructType
```

Really appreciate if I can get some help on it.

code below for casting and loading.

```
dynamic_frame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type="mongodb",
                                                  connection_options=read_mongo_options)
user_df_cast = user_df.select(user_df.login.cast(StringType()),'name',user_df.notifications.cast(StringType()))
datasinkusers = user_df_cast.write.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME).options(**sfOptions).option("dbtable", "users").mode("append").save()
```

Comment: That error makes it look like Snowflake isn't even seeing the command, can you check your query history to confirm?  Also, it might make sense to do a debug command after you set user_df_cast, maybe check the "shape" print((df.count(), len(df.columns))) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `users` table in Snowflake has the following schema then *casting is not required*, as the [`StructType` fields of a SparkSQL DataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.html) will map to the [`VARIANT` type in Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html#variant) automatically:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
    login VARIANT
   ,name STRING
   ,notifications VARIANT
   ,query VARIANT
)
```

Just do the following, no transformations required because the Snowflake Spark Connector [understands the data-type](https://github.com/snowflakedb/spark-snowflake/blob/v2.5.5-spark_2.3/src/main/scala/net/snowflake/spark/snowflake/SnowflakeJDBCWrapper.scala#L244-L268) and will convert to appropriate JSON representations on its own:

```py
user_df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
  connection_type="mongodb",
  connection_options=read_mongo_options
)

user_df
  .toDF()
  .write
  .format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
  .options(**sfOptions)
  .option("dbtable", "users")
  .mode("append")
  .save()
```

If you absolutely need to store the `StructType` fields as plain JSON strings, you'll need to explicitly transform them using the [`to_json` SparkSQL function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_json):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_json

user_df_cast = user_df.select(
  to_json(user_df.login),
  user_df.name,
  to_json(user_df.notifications)
)
```

This will store JSON strings as simple `VARCHAR` types which will not let you leverage Snowflake's [semi-structured data storage and querying capabilities](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-semistructured.html) directly without a [`PARSE_JSON`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/parse_json.html) step (inefficient).

Consider using the `VARIANT` approach shown above, which will allow you to perform queries on the fields directly:

```sql
SELECT
    login:login_attempts
   ,login:last_attempt
   ,name
   ,notifications:weekly_summary.enabled
FROM users
```

Comment: I get "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'format'" error event after using the latest version of spark and snowflake jdbc drivers

Comment: I'm assuming the above code works for nested structtype too. 

An error occurred while calling o86.save.  com.mongodb.spark.exceptions.MongoTypeConversionException: Cannot cast ARRAY into a StructType(StructField(city,StructType(StructField(term,StringType,true), StructField(status,StringType,true), StructField(source,StringType,true), StructField(length,NullType,true), StructField(sort,StringType,true), StructField(current_page,IntegerType,true), StructField(new_page,IntegerType,true), StructField(first_id,NullType,true)........)}}. It throws the following error

Comment: Nope, I'm not casting anywhere in the code and still its throwing this error. Just using your code as it is